# Attempt to migrate SQL Server database to Azure fails with login failed

Tags: sql-server, azure, migrate

In SSMS, I'm trying to use the "Deploy Database to SQL Azure Database" utility.

I'm moving a small local database in SQL Server 2012 to Azure for hosting. But after entering the host database server connection parameters I always get a "Login Failed for user,...." error, referencing the name of the local database to be created on the server.

Why this would fail is unclear, since the database does not exist on the cloud server yet. Here is what I have done:

- Set up a firewall exception for my local IP address.
- Confirmed my server administrator user name and password

So now I am left guessing... Locally I use Windows Authentication. If a database is to be moved to the server, does it have to have SQL Server authentication, as is required on Azure host?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have the SQL server Authentication enabled in order to be able to login to your database when you move it to Azure.

Once, you login through SQL server authentication, you can create your users then and have different logins for different users.

Hope this helps!

Comment: So I have to change my LOCAL authentication mode to SQL Server BEFORE I can migrate it to Azure?